# Simple Reading file query

Tags: c

Im trying to print 24 lines of a random text file at a time, waiting for an enter key press between each print. However my check only happens the first time, so the first 24 are printed, it waits for an enter keypress then printing the rest without performing the check again. Any ideas why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

FILE *mystream;
char mystring[100];
int nullcount =0;
int key;

if(argc<2){
     printf("Please provide a filename as an input\n");
}
else{

    mystream = fopen(argv[1], "r");  //open the file for writing

    if(mystream !=NULL){ // file steam pointer should n't be NULL if everything worked...

        while( fgets(mystring,100, mystream) !=NULL )
        {
            printf("%s", mystring);
            printf("%d", nullcount);
            nullcount++;
            if(nullcount==24)
            {
                nullcount = 0;
                while(key !='\n')
                {
                    key=getchar();
                    if(key=='q') return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(mystream); // close the file
    }
    else{
        printf("something went wrong trying to open the file\n");

    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file isn't fully read? you're reading 100 characters at a time and incrementing `nullcount` after you read 100 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this `while` loop:

```
while(key !='\n')
{
    key=getchar();
    if(key=='q') return 0;
}
```

After the user presses Enter, `key` will be equal to `'\n'` and the while loop will stop as expected. But the next time this part is reached, `key` is still `'\n'`, so the `while` loop will never be entered again and `getchar()` won't be called.

You should change it to a `do {...} while` loop so that the body is executed at least once.

Comment: Thanks mate you're right, just added 
    if(key=='\n') key=0;
to the top of the while loop that sorted it!

Comment: @user3062510 It should just be `key=0;` because `key` is uninitialized in your code. But as I said it's better to use `do { ... } while (key != '\n');`